# Filter pandas dataframe, row value must be higher than an offset max value of the column, per customer

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a dataframe of orders containing Customer ID, Order ID, Revenue and Order Date
Like so:

| Customer ID | Order ID | Revenue | Order Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 | 05-08-2022 |
| B | 2 | 10 | 04-07-2022 |
| C | 3 | 10 | 05-02-2022 |

And so forth. I am trying to copy this dataframe but only keeping each row where a given customers order date, is between the latest order date and three months prior to it. I.e. the condition is variable for each row.

I've tried something like this

```
df_filtered = df.loc[df['Order Date']>=(df.max(['Date Order']- DateOffset(months=3)))]
```

But get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'DateOffset'"

I've also tried to create a separate dataframe where I've grouped by Customer ID and calculated the date 3 months prior to latest purchase.

Like this:

| Customer ID | Last_purchase_3M |
| --- | --- |
| A | 05-05-2022 |
| B | 04-04-2022 |
| C | 05-12-2021 |

With the intention to do something like this:

```
df_filtered = df.loc[df['Order Date']>=df_list['last_purchase_3M'] & df['Customer ID'] == df_list['Customer ID']]
```

But this gives me this error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'str'".

I clearly don't know what I am doing here (also I'm new to this;))

Am I on the right track or is this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Three is a dtype issue here

`df_filtered = df.loc[df['Order Date']>=(df.max(['Date Order']- DateOffset(months=3)))]`

Try

```
df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'])
df_filtered = df.loc[df['Order Date'].ge(df['Order Date'].max()- DateOffset(months=3))]
```

Comment: Halfway there. It looks like it is the same max() date which is considered for every row. As I mentioned I am looking for a way to consider the maximum value (latest order date) for each customer, offset it by 3 months and get all rows with more recent Order Date. Thus the the considered date range is different per Customer ID.